# Using z-index on divs that are inline-block

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

[image]

Here's the code reference of the image:
https://jsfiddle.net/u3ouar6d/11/

How can I make the [image] checkmarks of `C` and `D` appear on top of the vertical line just like `A` and `B`?

I've tried putting `z-index` on the `box_left` and `box_mid` but doesn't appear to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z-index only applies when an element is positioned. Try adding:

```
.bullet_right,
.bullet_left {
  position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u3ouar6d/14/